# How do i modify BigCommerce Files from my my pc?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am working on a BigCommerce website and i'm using the online editor to modify HTML files but i can't modify js files because they are read only files 
How can I work on my pc and sync modifications with the website .???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are modifying theme files, and you are using a Stencil theme, then you can download the theme's files, edit them locally and add them back to the site.

See:

- [Installing Stencil](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/getting-started/installing-stencil)
- [Theme Documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/getting-started/about-stencil)